# How to install "npm install react-youtube" ? (ERROR)

Tags: git, react-native, npm, cmd, npm-install

When I try to run "npm install react-youtube" I have these errors. I don't know where they come from nor how the resuders.

How to solve this problem and install "react-youtube"?

I am novice. Any help will be very appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you installed, or tried using git? npm install --save npm-git-install

Comment: Yes I just tried and always the same errors.

Comment: is this the only library that gives you problems when installing?

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshots its trying to download the module from the GFithub repository. But you can't clone it trough the command line because you properly haven't installed git. Try running the `git -v` command and see if the command is found (it will return a version number if git is found). If its not found try to install git by following this guide: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: I install the git that is proposed on this link [link](http://git-scm.com/download/win) but I encounter errors again : [link](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/48/5/1543583627-error-1.png) and [link](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/48/5/1543583631-error-2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Youtube in your react-native project. I recommend you using this package [react-native-youtube-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube)

The documentation is clear.

**Edit :**

If you want to play a bunch of videos, then you could use `playlistId` from the package.

Comment: I want to share all the videos of a channel list. Do you know how to do that? My errors persist, I can't use "import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube'"